# How to programmatically terminate a workflow instance running as a workflow service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am using windows workflow service and would like to programmatically terminate a specific workflow instance via a web service request without building this into the workflow itself.

By building it into the workflow itself, I mean having a specific Receive activity which will be responsible for terminating the activity.

So I am imagining something like:

```
http://myhost/myworkflowservice/myworkflow.xamlx/terminate
```

Does this type of functionality exist?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a [Workflow Control Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358723.aspx) which allows one to call remote operations on workflow service. Add it through *web.config*:

```
<endpoint address="<endpoint_address>" binding="basicHttpBinding" kind="workflowControlEndpoint" />
```

Then you can use [WorkflowControlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.workflowcontrolclient.aspx) to call control messages (Run, Cancel, Suspend, etc.) to a WorkflowControlEndpoint.

Comment: This seems promising.  Appreciate the answer.

Comment: The "WCF Workflow Service Application" project template does not create a web.config with a `<service>` node for the service. How do you add the control endpoint in this case?  I swear this information does not exist anywhere on the internet...