# WCF Workflow Service - How to add Workflow Control Endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I've created a new WCF Workflow Service project in VS2012.

Ultimately, what I need is the ability to terminate instance B of my workflow from instance A of my workflow.

As best I can tell, the only way to achieve that is via the [Workflow Control Endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358723.aspx), but I can't figure out how to add/access that to my project.

From what I've seen (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966085/how-to-programmatically-terminate-a-workflow-instance-running-as-a-workflow-serv)), to add the control endpoint, you just add an `<endpoint>` element to `<service>` node in web.config with the appropriate attribute values. The problem is.. I don't have a `<service>` element in my web.config. The "WCF Workflow Service Application" project template does not add one. My web.config is below.

So my question is simply: **Starting from the "WCF Workflow Service Application" project template, how do I add a Workflow Control Endpoint?**

These are the default launch settings for the project:
[image: default launch settings]

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution for this. See [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5279fc5f-8a53-43e7-8ef2-3073808dc90f/configuring-workflow-services-how-to-configure-workflow-control-endpoint?forum=wfprerelease).